# Neural Network for classifying humans

Tags: neural-network, image-classification

I am currently searching a neural network that can classify if there is a human in an image or not.

I checked the ImageNet dataset, but the 1000 classes there contain nothing like human or person or such, mostly animals and things.

Segmentation CNNs usually have a lot longer runtime, and all I really need is basically a binary NN, just "Yes = Human in Image", "No = No human in image". Can someone point me to a training set or a pre-trained network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Part 1](https://medium.com/@madhawavidanapathirana/https-medium-com-madhawavidanapathirana-real-time-human-detection-in-computer-vision-part-1-2acb851f4e55) of this "tutorial/discussion" ther is a good explanation of the problem and a possible solution using OpenCV built in [**Haar Cascades**](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html)  or [**HOG**](https://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/) for *Human Detection* (this is the key-word you should use to search info about your task).

They are both really fast compared to NN and require little training.

In [Part 2](https://medium.com/@madhawavidanapathirana/real-time-human-detection-in-computer-vision-part-2-c7eda27115c6) are explained more modern approaches using Deep Learning. A notable mention would be AlexNet.

At the end there is even a tutorial on **Setting up a Basic Human Detector** with Tensorflow.